# Sending GET to third party

Tags: php, forms, post, get, sms

I'm trying to set up a SMS system and using aql.com to send text(SMS) messages.

This works fine in a browser:
  http://gw1.aql.com/sms/postmsg.php?to_num=447943417499&message=HELLO&flash=0&originator=Me&username=&password=***

I got it to work in PHP the other night using a simple header() function. I can't get it to work now with header, ob_start/flush, fsock etc.

What is the best and reliable method to send a GET request in this instance. Could I have a  basic example?

Thanks in advance, :-)

[Edit] The page is requested via the SMS provider upon a text message received so debugging is pretty difficult especially on a shared host!!

Comment: curl - http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php . it might seem confusing at first but after reading a couple of examples you should be able to do what you want quite easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is pear class for this service [here](http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=59)

Also here is another implementation:

```
function dosmsend($number, $message, $flash = "") {
    // your aql username and password
    $username = "yourusername";
    $password = "yourpassword";

    $weburl = "http://gw1.aql.com/sms/postmsg.php";

    // encodes your message for sending on the web
    $message = urlencode($message);


    // the request string
    $smsurl = "$weburl?username=$username&password=$password&to_num=$number&message=$message";


    // if $flash is set to 1, it will add the flash request onto the query
    if ($flash == "1")
        $smsurl .= "&flash=1";

    // connects to server to send message
    if ($content_array = file($smsurl)) {
        $content = implode("", $content_array);

        // check for response
        if (eregi("AQSMS-AUTHERROR", $content))
        echo "There was an authenication error";
        elseif (eregi("AQSMS-NOMSG", $content))
        echo "There was no message or mobile number";
        elseif (eregi("AQSMS-OK", $content))
        echo "The Message was queued succcessfully";
        elseif (eregi("AQSMS-NOCREDIT", $content))
        echo "Your account has no credit";
    }
    else
        echo "There was an error connecting to the server";
}

dosmsend("09978123456", "this is a test message");

//or 
//dosmsend("09978123456","this is a test flash message oo!","1");
```

Comment: I searched the site for a PHP example but only found C# samples. Considering the technology involved their website isn't great, information wise. The function works, thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

For most business scenarios, dealing with a third party should be kept to a limit as you want to have as much control over your operation as possible, except when it comes to the business of affiliate marketing and the concept of getting rich with these programs.